# If $u \in H^1(0,\infty)$, does $u_x(\infty) = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, greens-theorem

Let $u \in H^1(0,\infty)$. Then is it true that $u'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

I am wondering by Green's formula/IBP in this setting; do I get something like
$$\int_0^\infty u_{xx}v = -\int_0^\infty u_xv_x + u_x(0)v(0)?$$

Comment: Generally no, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} u'(x)$ need not exist (*if* it exists, it must be $0$). But by writing $\int_0^\infty u_{xx} v$, you impose more than $H^1$ on $u$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see. Well I am trying to find weak formulation of equations of the form $u_{xx} = f$ so the displayed equation in my OP whould be useful because I don't want something at infinity. So I think given your comment it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $H^1$- functions, this does not hold in general. It is basically the same argument that $L^2$- functions generally do not vanish at $\infty$, you just have to take such a function and integrate it, for example a bump function where the bumps get thinner when you go outside.

For $H^2$-functions however, it does hold: Take
$$\int_0^a f'(x)f''(x)^*+f'(x)^*f''(x)^=|f'(a)|^2-|f'(0)|^2$$
As $f',f''$ are $L^2$, the product $f'f''$ is $L^1$, so the above expression has to be finite if you send $a$ to infinity. Because $f'$ is also $L^2$, it can only go to 0.

Comment: thanks but can you explain your last sentence a bit?

Comment: Assume $|f'(a)|^2$ would go to some nonzero number, say $c>0$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there would exist a $d>0$, such that $|f'(x)|^2>c-\epsilon$ for all $x>d$. This contradicts the fact that $f'$ is $L^2$,  as the integral would go to infinity because $\int_d^\infty c-\epsilon dx$ is obviously not bounded for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.